# Passing string parameter JPA native query

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a native query I want to pass parameters to the following query:

```
SELECT dqlist.*,score(1) AS rank FROM dq_list_hash_full dqlist WHERE contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy(, 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0
```

I am using the question mark operator but somehow it is not understanding and giving me SQL grammer exception:

Here is my try:

```
SELECT dqlist.*,score(1) AS rank FROM dq_list_hash_full dqlist WHERE contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy('?1', 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0
```

My JPA repo method:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value="SELECT\r\n" + 
        "     a.EXTERNALID_ENC,\r\n" + 
        "     a.EXTERNALID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.TELNUMBER,\r\n" + 
        "     a.TELAREACODE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DQ_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DQ_ARABIC_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.NAMEFIELD_1,\r\n" + 
        "     a.USAGETYPE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.STATE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.REGION,\r\n" + 
        "     a.LOCALITY,\r\n" + 
        "     a.ADDITIONALLOCALITYINFO,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_TEXT_7,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_1,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_4,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_9,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_10,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_ARABIC_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_EMIRATE_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_PARTY_ID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_ACCOUNT_ID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.RECORD_ID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DISPLAY_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DISPLAY_FLAG_GROUP,\r\n" + 
        "     a.LONGITUDE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.LATITUDE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.NORMALIZED_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_PARTY_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_PARTY_ARABIC_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.MANUAL_UPDATE_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.RULE_UPDATE_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.BUSINESS_UPDATE_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.EXCEL_UPDATE_FLAG\r\n" + 
        "     \r\n" + 
        " FROM\r\n" + 
        "     (\r\n" + 
        "         SELECT\r\n" + 
        "             *\r\n" + 
        "         FROM\r\n" + 
        "             (\r\n" + 
        "                 SELECT\r\n" + 
        "                     dqlist.*,\r\n" + 
        "                     score(1) AS rank\r\n" + 
        "                 FROM\r\n" + 
        "                     dq_list_hash_full dqlist\r\n" + 
        "                 WHERE\r\n" + 
        "                     contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy(?1, 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0\r\n" + 
        "                 UNION\r\n" + 
        "                 SELECT\r\n" + 
        "                     dqlist.*,\r\n" + 
        "                     score(1) AS rank\r\n" + 
        "                 FROM\r\n" + 
        "                     dq_list_hash_full dqlist\r\n" + 
        "                 WHERE\r\n" + 
        "                     contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'!?1' ,1) > 0\r\n" + 
        "             )\r\n" + 
        "         ORDER BY\r\n" + 
        "             rank DESC\r\n" + 
        "     ) a\r\n" + 
        "")
public List<DqListHashFullEntity> findByEngName(@Param("englishName") String englishName);

@Query(value="SELECT\r\n" + 
        "     a.EXTERNALID_ENC,\r\n" + 
        "     a.EXTERNALID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.TELNUMBER,\r\n" + 
        "     a.TELAREACODE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DQ_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DQ_ARABIC_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.NAMEFIELD_1,\r\n" + 
        "     a.USAGETYPE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.STATE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.REGION,\r\n" + 
        "     a.LOCALITY,\r\n" + 
        "     a.ADDITIONALLOCALITYINFO,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_TEXT_7,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_1,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_4,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_9,\r\n" + 
        "     a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_10,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_ARABIC_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_EMIRATE_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_PARTY_ID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_ACCOUNT_ID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.RECORD_ID,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DISPLAY_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.DISPLAY_FLAG_GROUP,\r\n" + 
        "     a.LONGITUDE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.LATITUDE,\r\n" + 
        "     a.NORMALIZED_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_PARTY_ENGLISH_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.CBCM_PARTY_ARABIC_NAME,\r\n" + 
        "     a.MANUAL_UPDATE_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.RULE_UPDATE_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.BUSINESS_UPDATE_FLAG,\r\n" + 
        "     a.EXCEL_UPDATE_FLAG\r\n" + 
        "     \r\n" + 
        " FROM\r\n" + 
        "     (\r\n" + 
        "         SELECT\r\n" + 
        "             *\r\n" + 
        "         FROM\r\n" + 
        "             (\r\n" + 
        "                 SELECT\r\n" + 
        "                     dqlist.*,\r\n" + 
        "                     score(1) AS rank\r\n" + 
        "                 FROM\r\n" + 
        "                     dq_list_hash_full dqlist\r\n" + 
        "                 WHERE\r\n" + 
        "                     contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'!?1',1) > 0\r\n" + 
        "             )\r\n" + 
        "         ORDER BY\r\n" + 
        "             rank DESC\r\n" + 
        "     ) a\r\n" + 
        "", nativeQuery=true)
public List<DqListHashFullEntity> findByEngNameTwo(@Param("englishName") String englishName);
```

I know I am missing something here. Can anybody help me out please?

Edit 1 : I have added the JPA method with whole native query the englishName parameter is binded in two places.

SQL generated in the logs:

```
 SELECT
 a.EXTERNALID_ENC,
 a.EXTERNALID,
 a.TELNUMBER,
 a.TELAREACODE,
 a.DQ_ENGLISH_NAME,
 a.DQ_ARABIC_NAME,
 a.NAMEFIELD_1,
 a.USAGETYPE,
 a.STATE,
 a.REGION,
 a.LOCALITY,
 a.ADDITIONALLOCALITYINFO,
 a.GEN_TEXT_7,
 a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_1,
 a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_4,
 a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_9,
 a.GEN_SHORTTEXT_10,
 a.CBCM_ENGLISH_NAME,
 a.CBCM_ARABIC_NAME,
 a.CBCM_EMIRATE_NAME,
 a.CBCM_PARTY_ID,
 a.CBCM_ACCOUNT_ID,
 a.RECORD_ID,
 a.DISPLAY_FLAG,
 a.DISPLAY_FLAG_GROUP,
 a.LONGITUDE,
 a.LATITUDE,
 a.NORMALIZED_ENGLISH_NAME,
 a.CBCM_PARTY_ENGLISH_NAME,
 a.CBCM_PARTY_ARABIC_NAME,
 a.MANUAL_UPDATE_FLAG,
 a.RULE_UPDATE_FLAG,
 a.BUSINESS_UPDATE_FLAG,
 a.EXCEL_UPDATE_FLAG

 FROM
     (
         SELECT
             *
         FROM
             (
                 SELECT
                     dqlist.*,
                     score(1) AS rank
                 FROM
                     dq_list_hash_full dqlist
                 WHERE
                     contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy(?1, 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0
                 UNION
                 SELECT
                     dqlist.*,
                     score(1) AS rank
                 FROM
                     dq_list_hash_full dqlist
                 WHERE
                     contains(dqlist.dq_english_name, '!Bhularam' ,1) > 0
             )
         ORDER BY
             rank DESC
     ) a
```

Comment: You definitely need to remove the quotes around '?1'.

Comment: It is taking ?1 one as a String to search not the parameter value.

Comment: Can you update your question. Add the query as it is defined in your java code.

Comment: Just made a edit. Please have a look.

Comment: Enable SQL logging. Add the generated SQL query together with the exception message.

Comment: @AlanHay just added. Please have a look.

Comment: Don't you need to remove the single quotes around `'definescore(fuzzy(?1, 1, 6, weight),relevance)'`? Additionally, try using `:englishName` rather than `?1`

Comment: After removing the quotes I get the following error:
ORA-00904: "DEFINESCORE": invalid identifier

Comment: And by :englishName it is treating it as a static string not the parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a struggle I finally able to come up with a solution. I have use the '||' operator as it is used for String concatenation in Oracle. So my solution is:

```
SELECT dqlist,score(1) AS rank FROM dq_list_hash_full dqlist WHERE contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy('||?1||', 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work by replacing '?1' with ?
So all you have to do is remove the 1 and the '. You can work with multiple parameters by putting multiple ? There's no need to number or escape them

Answer (score 0):

The Query should be like this

```
SELECT dqlist,score(1) AS rank FROM dq_list_hash_full dqlist WHERE contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy('?1', 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0
```

the .* is not needed here
then before exceuting the query you need to set the param as

```
query.setParameter(1, "ABC").getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  :1

> SELECT dqlist,score(1) AS rank FROM dq_list_hash_full dqlist WHERE
>   contains(dqlist.dq_english_name,'definescore(fuzzy(:1, 1, 6,
>   weight),relevance)',1) > 0

This should work

Comment: Have tried this already. What this does it takes that :1 as a String not the parameter value hence resulting wrong query result.

Answer (score 0):

try :1 instead of ?1. It will work.